# Parse text file line by line and store data in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, explode

I do not care about security at this point.  I have been stuck on this code for 4 days.  Please help.  This is the code I have at this point.  I am uploading a text file inside my php web application.  Upload is successful.  I move the file to a directory and this works also.  I just need help with the parsing algorithm during the foreach loop.  It will store the two values once then it wont ever do it again. I already have the database settings saved in my file.  The text file is tab delimited and all the data types are right in the database table.

```
     $file_name= $_FILES['file1']['name'];
     $add= "uploads/$file_name";
     $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $add);
     $get = file_get_contents("$add");
     $delimiter = "\n";
     $line = explode($delimiter, $get);
     foreach ($line as $value => $data) {
         $delimiter = "\t";
         $tab = explode($delimiter, $data);
         $datetime = $tab[0];
         $deltatime = $tab[1]; 
         $sql = "INSERT INTO RobotData (datetime, deltatime) VALUES('$datetime', '$deltatime')"; 
         $store = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     }
```

Comment: done any basic debugging like `var_dump($line)` to see if you exploded properly? how about `var_dump($tab)`?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the data?

Comment: example of data:(one line)       6/17/2013 3:35:49 PM 55.0031

Comment: I have tested whether the 2nd explode function stores it into an array and it does..

Comment: Maybe if you showed us ALL the relevant code, at least to the end of the foreach loop it would become quite obvious

Comment: Use load data infile command if available instead of trying to insert rows one by one. This is the slowest possible method of inserting data into any rdbms.

Comment: the store variable is the end followed by a curly brace

Comment: Maybe if you also mentioned what the actual problem is we could save a little time as well

Comment: Where's the closing `}` on your foreach block?  Is there, in fact, something like a `die()` or `return` accidentally inside the block?  (UPDATE: just saw your comment saying there's nothing else in the block.)

Comment: i have the closing curly brace in my code.. the actual problem is that its not storing data after the 2nd explode function.. I have proven successfully by printing out the array so I know the array is good.

Comment: Add `if ( $store === false ) { echo mysqli_error($conn); exit; }` after the `mysqli_query()` line. Always test the result of almost all `mysqli_` api calls

Comment: how would I use the load data infile sql query?

Comment: I have that already in my code RIGGS.. youre looking at my "meat and potatoes" of my attempt at parsing and storing

Comment: what you're seeing is my parsing algorithm that I am trying to get to work

Comment: No you dont? Where is it? If you give us pseudo code ___all you will get is pseudo GUESSES___

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this and let me know

```
$file_name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$add = "uploads/$file_name";
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $add);

$handle = fopen($add, "r");

if ($handle) {

    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        $arr = explode("\t", $line);
        $datetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($arr[0]);
        $deltatime = mysqli_real_escape_string($arr[1]);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO RobotData (datetime, deltatime) VALUES('$datetime', '$deltatime')";
        $store = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

**Edit**

Added escaping special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

Comment: Yes. you can add that. If you think my answer helped you solve your question then please accept it. ;)

Comment: Now I am running across the same problem I had this morning... When I get a script to work, I add another column of data in the text file then it wont store.  All i did was add another variable with index 2 and added column name and variable in sql query. They all match accordingly.. so aggravating lol

Comment: Any error? There might be mysql query error.  Add something like this `$store = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());` It will give us assurance on query is right or not

Comment: Use browser's developer tools or use view source code to check what's actually happening. I'm sure there is a syntactical problem here.

Comment: I'm re-configuring my web application environment.. so I'm hoping it works this time.. It worked once with 3 pieces of data then wouldn't let me store it again.. Same as before..

Comment: Does your file always contain same number of columns or pieces in each row? If not then, before adding or creating/concatenating query you should add a check.

Comment: I am just testing the algorithm one column at a time with different text files that have 1,2,3, etc columns.. my real text file has 32 columns of data..

Comment: it fails to execute $store because I always get the "You suck" message

Comment: What it shows after adding `mysqli_error()` ? since your $store is not returning `TRUE`, which means there is a mysql error.

Comment: its the blank screen again.. I just dont know what the error could be dealing with mysql

Comment: Execute my code again, and comment this line `$store = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` and add `echo $sql."</br>";`. This way you will able to see what query is passing, then execute that query manually going into phpmyadmin or any other application you are using. You will come to know that is there any error in the query.

Comment: im rebooting database to see if it will help

Comment: I don't think so rebooting will change anything. Because when you passed two parameters it worked, right?

Comment: INSERT INTO RobotData (datetime, deltatime) VALUES ('6/17/2013 3:35:49 PM', '55.0031')...  which is the right data that is being parsed

Comment: What is `datatype` for column `datetime` and `deltatime`? have you tried executing this query directly into `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: I appreciate all the help my man.. I cant believe it but somehow the first column data type got switched from nvarchar to varchar.. I guess my attention to detail failed.. lol  thanks for helping me troubleshoot

Comment: One last question.. I have only been parsing one line.. Will this algorithm parse more than one line or do I need to add another explode function with "/n"?

Comment: You're welcome bro! After looking into your data, I've edited my answer little bit. Please update accordingly in your code. Hopefully now everything will work :)

Comment: `fgets()` function reads each line till the end of file. You don't need to add another `explode()` function

Comment: thank you.. Im learning everyday.. Thats what is so good about the TECH field.. I luv it..

Comment: Great!! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) - it was created to extra fast loading large amount of data from text files:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/full/path/to/text/file'
INTO TABLE RobotData
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using now...

```
     $file_name= $_FILES['file1']['name'];
     $add= "uploads/$file_name";
     $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $add);
     $handle = fopen($add, "r");
     if ($handle) {
         while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE) {
            $delimiter = "\t";
            $tab = explode($delimiter, $line);
            $datetime = $tab[0];
            $deltatime = $tab[1];  
             $sql = "INSERT INTO RobotData (datetime, deltatime) VALUES ('$datetime', '$deltatime')"; 
             $store = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
              if($store === TRUE) {
                  fclose($handle);
                 $delete= unlink($add);
                 echo "YOU DID IT!!";
             }
             else {
                 fclose($handle);
                 $delete= unlink($add);
                 echo "YOU SUCK!!";
             }
         }
    }
    else {
         fclose($handle);
         $delete= unlink($add);
         echo "Something went wrong";
    }
```